# How to implement Facebook Custom Tab with less than 2k likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I saw in Facebooks Documentation that you can only create a custom Page tabs if a page has more than 2k likes, but why is it that I saw a facebook page that only has less than 700 likes but there's a Facebook Page Tab installed?

Here's their documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

> Limitations
>   Only Pages with 2000 or more likes can create custom Page
>   tabs.

This is the FB Page: https://www.facebook.com/basketkingdvo/?ref=page_internal - that page was just recently created too. It was Last April 20, 2020.

Why does that have a Custom Page Tab called "See MENU and Order" ?

Added Info:
I saw this into the section of their docs:

> /page/tabs — Creating custom tabs with POST operations will only be
>   available to Pages with 2000 or more fans, or pages managed by
>   whitelisted apps. Existing custom tabs will be unaffected.

My question is - How can I make my app whitelisted to a certain page?

Comment: Maybe the page _had_ 2k likes at the time they installed it.

Comment: I tried integrating the facebook app that they are using which is gloriafoods.com to my page with only 600 likes and i was able to integrate it successfully. How did they do that?

Comment: That is likely some “white listing” Facebook does for selected partners. There usually is no way to explicitly apply for such things.